# Testing timer using JUnit

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, junit, timertask

I'm trying to test my Timer and I can't seem to be able to execute my task more than 1 time...

how can I test this class so it can run multiple times?

here's my code

```
package rpm.mode.offline;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import rpm.logging.LOG;
import rpm.patient.properties.OptionsProperties;

public class ResendController {

private static final Logger LOG = new LOG().getLogger();

private static ResendController instance = new ResendController();
private static OfflineDataLayer staticofflineDataLayer;
private int nbRetriesAllowed = 0;
private int nbActualRetries = 0;
private int retryTimeDelay = 0;
Timer timer;

public static ResendController getInstance(OfflineDataLayer offlineDataLayer) {
    staticofflineDataLayer = offlineDataLayer;
    return instance;
}

private ResendController() {
    nbRetriesAllowed = Integer.parseInt(OptionsProperties.getProperty(OptionsProperties.RESEND_NUMBER_RETRIES));
    retryTimeDelay = Integer.parseInt(OptionsProperties.getProperty(OptionsProperties.RESEND_DELAY_IN_MINUTES));
}

public void sendAnswers() {
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new ResendTask(), 1);
        System.out.println("ResendTask task created...");
    }
}

/*
 * The Task that sends the answers of the patient.
 */
class ResendTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ResendTask run() is called....");
      }
}
```

}

and my Junit:

```
package rpm.mode.offline;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestResendController {

@Test
public void testResend() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Java timer is about to start");

    OfflineDataLayer datalayer = null;
    ResendController controller = ResendController.getInstance(datalayer);
    controller.sendAnswers();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 1...");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 2...");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 3...");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 4...");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 5...");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.print("Pass 6...");

}
}
```

Output:
ResendTask task created...
ResendTask run() is called....
Pass 1...Pass 2...Pass 3...Pass 4...Pass 5...Pass 6...

Answer (score 0):

Two issues: First, your test only is calling `sendAnswers()` once; are the alternating sleeps and prints that follow meant to have more calls to it?

Second, if `timer` is already set in ResendController, then `sendAnswers()` isn’t doing anything—it looks like you should have `timer.schedule()` after the `if` block, not inside it.

Comment: thanks, but I figured it out using timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ResendTask(), retryTimeDelay * 1000 * 60, 1000);

Comment: Ah, if that’s what you want. You will need to count the retries within ResendTask, and cancel the timer once they’re all up.